# Raising an event from child control to parent control

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, event-handling

I have a class (which extends Framework Element) which contains within it a number of other Elements.

```
    // Click event coverage area
    private Rectangle connectorRectangle;
```

These shapes all have their event handlers, and when the user clicks on them its working well. Now what I want is to be able to 'handle' a right-click on my class from outside the scope of the class.

So I figured the best way to do it is to handle the event internally, and somehow bubble it to the top

```
private void connectorRectangle_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)

        MouseButtonEventArgs args = new MouseButtonEventArgs();

        //???
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to raise the event. `this.OnMouseRightButtonUp` doesn't exist, and all the tutorials I'm finding are for raising custom events.

I'm pretty new to silverlight, so bear with me if I missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
public Rectangle
{    
   this.Click += new System.EventHandler(Function);  
}

private void Function(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if (((MouseEventArgs)e).Button == MouseButtons.Right)
   {
       //Your code         
   }
}
```

Comment: Rectangle is a built-in class. Also I'm not understanding what your code is trying to do. I know how to attach a handler, I just need the event to bubble from the child such that an attached handler at the parent's level works.

Answer (score 0):

Your "exteded Framework Element class" shouldn't handel the mouse event (or if they handel them, set e.Handled to false). Then the event should bubble up automatically (without reraise the event).

**EDIT**

```
public class ExtendedFrameworkElement : Grid
{
    public ExtendedFrameworkElement()
    {
        Border b1 = new Border();
        b1.Padding = new Thickness(20);
        b1.Background = Brushes.Red;
        b1.MouseRightButtonUp += b1_MouseRightButtonUp;

        Border b2 = new Border();
        b2.Padding = new Thickness(20);
        b2.Background = Brushes.Green;
        b2.MouseRightButtonUp += b2_MouseRightButtonUp;

        b1.Child = b2;

        this.Children.Add(b1);
    }

   private void b1_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //DoSomeThing
        e.Handled = false;
    }

  private void b2_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //DoSomeThing
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationTest.MainWindow">
    <wpfApplicationTest:ExtendedFrameworkElement MouseRightButtonUp="UIElement_OnMouseRightButtonUp"/>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void UIElement_OnMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //DoSomeThing
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working. Without the handler it is still not reaching the top.

Comment: I have updated my post. Is this what you want to do? This code works fine for me.

Comment: From which class ExtendedFrameworkElement inherits in your code?